# Concatenating DataFrames and offsetting integer indices

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, concatenation

I've a dict of DataFrames I've retrieved and I want to concatenate them together into one large DataFrame. Each DataFrame was retrieved successively, and each has an index column which is an integer index from `0` to `n-1`. Each dataframe has at most n dataframes.

```py
for i in range(no_of_pages):
        records_offset = i * records_limit
        response = my_api_client.get_dataframes(limit=records_limit,                                        
                                                offset=records_offset)
        page = response.get_result()
        pages[i] = page
```

Each DataFrame value of page looks something like:

```
    a    b    c 
0   1    1    "Dog"   
1   0    0    "Monkey"   
2   0    0    "Banana"   
3   1    1    "Cat"   
4   1    0    "Blue Whale"   
..  ... ...  ...
999 0    1    "Pangolin"
```

and the next page might look like:

```
    a    b    c 
0   1    1    "Clownfish"   
1   1    1    "Tompot Blenny"   
2   0    0    "Scorpionfish"   
3   0    1    "Grey Seal"   
4   0    0    "Beluga Whale"   
..  ... ...  ...
56  0    0    "Bearing Sea Cow"
```

My goal is to perform a `pd.concat()` over all DataFrame pages, but add the `records_offset` to the index column.

```
    a    b    c 
0   1    1    "Dog"   
1   0    0    "Monkey"   
2   0    0    "Banana"   
3   1    1    "Cat"   
4   1    0    "Blue Whale"   
..  ... ...  ...
1056  0    0    "Bearing Sea Cow"
```

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this during the loop before its even added to the dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reseting the index

```
result = pd.concat[pages.values()].reset_index(drop=True)
```